# How to make System.Windows.MessageBox buttons styled?

Tags: wpf, styles, messagebox

I'm using System.Windows.MessageBox in a WPF app, and for some reason its buttons are styled the Windows 2000 way - not WinXP, not Aero, not the WPF default. Just gray with basic 3d borders.

How can I make them appear with a more modern style? (doesn't really matter which one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix this with a manifest. See this article for step-by-step instructions: [Why am I Getting Old Style File Dialogs and Message Boxes with WPF](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/28/Why-am-I-Getting-Old-Style-File-Dialogs-and-Message.aspx)

Basically, you have to add an XML file called a 'manifest' to your application.

Update:

Actually, it is very easy to do this in VS2008. Go to Project Properties->Application and click the 'View UAC Settings' button. This will automatically create an application manifest file and open it. Edit this file as follows:

Just after the line:

```
</trustInfo>
```

Paste in the following dependency section:

```
  <!-- Activate Windows Common Controls v6 usage (XP and Vista): -->
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

My complete manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <!-- Activate Windows Common Controls v6 usage (XP, Vista, Win 7) to support themed dialogs: -->
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

After doing this, just build your app, run, and voila, the MessageBox dialog buttons take on the system theme style.

Comment: For information, it's even easier now with Visual Studio 2010, simply add a manifest to your application (Add, New Item..., Application Manifest File), and everything is already there. Uncomment the last group at the bottom which will produce the same file as shown in this post.